# view jscroll on particular div hover

Tags: jquery, hover, jscrollpane

I have a three div's on a page & each div have his own scroll. i am trying to view scroll on the hover of particular div the function is below.. Plz have any suggestion. function is currently working but on hover it show all scrolls of page (means 3 scrolls of these 3 div's) because each div has a same class & I can not change a class or cant add ID to div..

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('.leftPanelFixed').hover(function(){     
$('.jspVerticalBar').addClass('viewScroll');    
            },     
function(){    
         $('.jspVerticalBar').removeClass('viewScroll');     
});
});
```

Comment: each div has a "leftPanelFixed" class so when I hover on first div it also show the remaining two Div's scroll too.. this is the real problem

Comment: any one have a any answer...

Answer (score 0):

**Try;**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.leftPanelFixed').hover(function(){ 
       var $this = $(this);    
       $this.$('.jspVerticalBar').addClass('viewScroll');    
       },     
   function(){    
        $this.removeClass('viewScroll');     
   });
 });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answers - for example, what is different in this code and why it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
If I am not wrong for what you wanna do, following is the code

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
        width:600px; 
        margin:20px auto;
}
.leftPanelFixed{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    position:relative;
}
.jspVerticalBar{
    background:#999;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    display:none;
}
.viewscroll{
        display:inline-block !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="leftPanelFixed"><span class="jspVerticalBar">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="leftPanelFixed"><span class="jspVerticalBar">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="leftPanelFixed"><span class="jspVerticalBar">&nbsp;</span></div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('div.leftPanelFixed').hover(function(){      $(this).find('span').addClass('viewscroll').parent('div').siblings().find('span').removeClass('viewscroll');

        });   
    });
</script>
</html>
```